# mongo: how to retrieve the document exactly matching a field whose type is number or array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e068438c24cdec0eeb9"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123, "abc" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eeba"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123, "abc", "efg" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebb"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : "0xmd5md5md5" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebc"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebd"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : 123 }
```

The 'extraid' field is a number or array, and when I run operation below, returned result is not I want:

```
> db.foo.find({"extraid": 123})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e068438c24cdec0eeb9"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123, "abc" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eeba"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123, "abc", "efg" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebc"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebd"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : 123 }
```

I think there is only one document is matched, this is my expected result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebd"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : 123 }
```

I also try to run `$type` operator so that it can match exactly, but the result is still not I want:

```
> db.foo.find({"extraid": {"$eq": 123, "$type":"int"}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e068438c24cdec0eeb9"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123, "abc" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eeba"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123, "abc", "efg" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebc"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebd"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : 123 }
> db.foo.find({"extraid": {"$eq": 123, "$type":"array"}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e068438c24cdec0eeb9"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123, "abc" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eeba"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123, "abc", "efg" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebc"), "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr", "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete", "extraid" : [ 123 ] }
>
```

`$type: array` can match all array type of 'extraid', but `$type: int` is not work.

So who knows how to retrieve the document exactly matching a field whose type is number or array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.foo.find({$expr : {$and : [{$eq : ['int', {$type :'$extraid'}]}, {$eq : ["$extraid", 123]}]}})
```

**Note :** Check data in `extraid` field then use `double` instead of `int` if needed.

**Data in Collection :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e068438c24cdec0eeb9"),
    "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr",
    "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete",
    "extraid" : [ 
        123.0, 
        "abc"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eeba"),
    "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr",
    "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete",
    "extraid" : [ 
        123.0, 
        "abc", 
        "efg"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebb"),
    "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr",
    "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete",
    "extraid" : "0xmd5md5md5"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebc"),
    "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr",
    "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete",
    "extraid" : [ 
        123.0
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebd"),
    "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr",
    "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete",
    "extraid" : 123
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0ee11"),
    "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr",
    "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete",
    "extraid" : 12301
}
```

**Output :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4e3e078438c24cdec0eebd"),
    "from" : "0xabsdfeeqwsfdasfafaefegr",
    "to" : "0xfdshshrtfafdfadfaete",
    "extraid" : 123
}
```